# Result Difference Between Pandas DataFrame and Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Suppose that we have a data frame as below:

| Date | A | B | Div | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/01/2021 | 1229.23 | 1670.006 | 1670.02 | 0.301210244 |
| 14/01/2021 | 1231.93 | 1673.659 | nan | 0.301210244 |
| 15/01/2021 | 1241.81 | 1687.033 | nan | 0.301210244 |
| 16/01/2021 | 1225.49 | 1664.389 | nan | 0.301210244 |
| 17/01/2021 | 1226.27 | 1665.448 | nan | 0.301210244 |

The above data frame can be generated using code below:

```
data = {'Date': ['2021-01-13', '2021-01-14', '2021-01-15', '2021-01-16', '2021-01-17'],
        'A': [1229.23, 1231.93, 1241.81, 1225.49, 1226.27],
        'B': [1670.006, 1673.659, 1687.033, 1664.389, 1665.448],
        'Div': [1670.02, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'Rate':[0.301210244, 0.301210244, 0.301210244, 0.301210244, 0.301210244]}

tester = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I've filled nans in `Div` using code below and similar operation was performed on excel.

**Python Code**

```
tester['Div'] = (tester['Div'].combine_first(
            ((tester['B']) / (tester['B']).shift()) -
            (((tester['B']) / (tester['B']).shift()) -
             ((tester['A']) / (tester['A']).shift())) * tester['Rate']).cumprod())
```

**Excel Formula**

Assume we start from Date is in Row 1 of Column A the formula to derive `Excel` column is as follow:

```
=F2/((C2/C3)-(((C2/C3)-(B2/B3))*E2))
```

Resulting data frame:

| Date | A | B | Div | Rate | Excel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13/01/2021 | 1229.23 | 1670.006 | 1670.02 | 0.301210244 | 1670.02 |
| 14/01/2021 | 1231.93 | 1673.659 | 1673.677598 | 0.301210244 | 1673.677598 |
| 15/01/2021 | 1241.81 | 1687.033 | 1687.066397 | 0.301210244 | 1687.066397 |
| 16/01/2021 | 1225.49 | 1664.389 | 1664.564373 | 0.301210244 | 1664.564345 |
| 17/01/2021 | 1226.27 | 1665.448 | 1665.623591 | 0.301210244 | 1665.623562 |

I am stuck at figuring out why in last 2 rows, column `Div` and `Excel` have different results when both formula and used values are the same?

Which one is the correct value and why?

Comment: My guess would be due to precision. Note that it's not just the last row that's different. The last four rows are all different, starting enough decimal places out.

Comment: I am confused on which one is correct.

Comment: Both are correct, it depends on what level of precision you want.

Comment: At least for the last entry, Excel is closer. Using a higher precision of 100 digits, the (truncated) value for the calculation of the last entry is `1665.6235621460`
`